# How to draw track legend in Circos

Tags: circos

This Circos [tutorial](http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/ideograms/spacing_breaks/images) showed configuring spacing between two chromosomes, so track legend can be placed in the area.
[image: example]
<sub>(source: [circos.ca](http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/ideograms/spacing_breaks/img/03.png))</sub>

Like the the example above, but I can't find any explanation about how to draw text there just like right circle.

Is it possible to draw track legend using configuration file, or I need to use a graphic editor add text manually on the output image?

Comment: You add the legend between chr1 and chrY manually, using picture editor, like inkskape, photoshop, etc. I don't think circos can add those legends as that coordinate is outside the ideogram.

Comment: @zx8754 Well, that is a pretty lame way considering if I made some tweaks to the configuration file, I had to manually add legend all over again. Circos should have come up with its own way to draw them using a configurable method.

Comment: I ended up keeping legend separate from the plot, in my case it made sense as I have more space on the ideogram. Also, GoogleGroups is more active place for support.